# "report.INFO: Broken reference:" in my system.log in magento 2.2

Tags: magento2.2

can someone explain why i have "report.INFO: Broken reference:" in my system.log in magento 2.2. how to fix it? Also there is another error that says:
report.INFO: Broken reference: the 'footer.bottom.links' tries to reorder itself towards 'copyright', but their parents are different: 'footer.bottom' and 'footer' respectively. [] []

[image]

Comment: Hi guru, how did solve the issue, i am getting same issue

https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/339869/57334

Answer (score 0):

hey in my knowledge it's a permission issue i also faced this issue and follow below stpes:

```
chown -R [apache-user:apache-group] .; && find . -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \; && find . -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
/usr/bin/php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy;
/usr/bin/php bin/magento cache:flush;
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this did not fix my issue. I had to add  missing parent blocks in <body> tag of default.xml. it worked for me.