# Magento 2 - How to solve report.INFO: Broken reference error

Tags: magento2.4.1, magento-2-commerce

How to solve the following error,

```
[2021-06-17 03:28:43] report.INFO: Broken reference: the 'catalog.compare.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2021-06-17 03:28:43] report.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sale.reorder.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2021-06-17 03:28:43] report.INFO: Broken reference: the 'wishlist_sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2021-06-17 03:28:43] report.INFO: Broken reference: the 'multiple-wishlist_sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2021-06-17 03:28:43] report.INFO: Broken reference: the 'yotpo_bottomline' element cannot be added as child to 'product.info.main', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2021-06-17 03:28:43] report.INFO: Broken reference: the 'paypal.partner.right.logo' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2021-06-17 03:28:43] report.INFO: Broken reference: the 'bml.right.logo' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2021-06-17 03:28:43] report.INFO: Broken reference: the 'yotpo_bottomline' tries to reorder itself towards 'product.info.addto', but their parents are different: 'product.info.main' and '' respectively. [] []
[2021-06-17 03:28:43] report.INFO: Broken reference: the 'wish-list-link-custom' tries to reorder itself towards 'minicart', but their parents are different: 'page.top' and 'header-wrapper' respectively. [] []
[2021-06-17 03:28:43] report.INFO: Broken reference: the 'navigation.sections' tries to reorder itself towards 'logo', but their parents are different: 'header-wrapper' and 'header.panel' respectively. [] []
[2021-06-17 03:28:43] report.INFO: Broken reference: the 'header.links' tries to reorder itself towards 'navigation.sections', but their parents are different: 'header.panel' and 'header-wrapper' respectively. [] []
[2021-06-17 03:28:48] report.INFO: Broken reference: the 'yotpo_bottomline' element cannot be added as child to 'product.info.main', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2021-06-17 03:28:48] report.INFO: Broken reference: the 'yotpo_bottomline' tries to reorder itself towards 'product.info.addto', but their parents are different: 'product.info.main' and '' respectively. [] []
[2021-06-17 03:28:48] report.INFO: Broken reference: the 'wish-list-link-custom' tries to reorder itself towards 'minicart', but their parents are different: 'page.top' and 'header-wrapper' respectively. [] []
[2021-06-17 03:28:48] report.INFO: Broken reference: the 'navigation.sections' tries to reorder itself towards 'logo', but their parents are different: 'header-wrapper' and 'header.panel' respectively. [] []
[2021-06-17 03:28:48] report.INFO: Broken reference: the 'header.links' tries to reorder itself towards 'navigation.sections', but their parents are different: 'header.panel' and 'header-wrapper' respectively. [] []
```

Comment: kindly share some more details

Comment: My backend and frontend showing text.

Comment: didn't understand

Comment: Sorry, screenshot : https://i.stack.imgur.com/PW0Sg.png

Comment: deploy static content if that doesnot resolve the problem check your .htaccess files from root directory and pub/static

Comment: does this helps? @zus

Comment: @AsadUllah Stil getting the issue i am just reinstalled.

Comment: did you find the solution? @zus

Comment: No, i reinstall my Magento